# What is another way to say 10 months?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm just curious because we call 10 years a decade.

> The word (decade) is derived (via French) from the Ancient Greek dekas which
>   means ten.

As sighted from wikipedia: [Decade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decade)

Is there another similar way to say 10 months?

Comment: No‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪.

Comment: Twenty-one point seven fortnights.

Comment: Almost a year..

Comment: What is the evidence that there is no single-word for this? How to confirm?

Comment: @Kris there is, in general, no way to prove a negative. In this case, we might say that if no word can be found with this definition in a dictionary, or set of dictionaries then the word can be considered not to exist. However, it's not a proof as no set of dictionaries can be proved to contain all the words in the English language. About all we can say is that we don't know of any such word, and if enough of us agree we can consider the matter settled. A counter example could come along someday and prove us all wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. There is no word for "ten months" because it's not necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree it is not necessary but, alas there doesn't seem to be a designated word.